# CUDF not reading columns properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, gpu, rapids, cudf

I'm trying to read a csv with cudf. It work nicely but when I try to get the content of the columns, it seems that cudf is not recognizing them at all. It's a very odd behavior :

Here is the code :

[image]

And here is the error :

[image]

any help please?

thanks

Comment: Your data was read into a dataframe as a single column, rather than multiple columns. It's likely either an issue with your data or a limitation in the cuDF CSV reader. I'd recommend creating a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to get additional assistance.

Comment: Indeed. I have an issue in the csv file. But when i created a minimal example with a csv containing 3 columns, A, B and C, cudf read it correctly but I'm unnable to get the first column

Comment: Resolved ! the issue was in the csv file. The format wasn't appropriate (because I created it in Excel with UTF-08 csv...) apparently cudf.read_csv doesnt recognize it. But anyways, it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Resolved ! the issue was in the csv file. The format wasn't appropriate (because I created it in Excel with UTF-08 csv...) apparently cudf.read_csv doesnt recognize it. But anyways, it worked. Thanks –